# How does DimensionReduce work for EventData?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, machine-learning

My question is whether the use of [`DimensionReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReduce.html), for a simple example with 
`Method ->  "PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"` is the equivalent to non-detect PCA, i.e. PCA for data, some of which are known only as an interval.

For example

```
data = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{3, 3, 3}, 
{{1, -0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 1, -0.25}, {0.5, -0.25, 1}} ], 1000];

eData = EventData /@ (data  /. {{_?(# < 1 &), y_, z_} -> {{0, 1.}, y, z}, 
{x_, _?(# < 1 &) , z_} -> {x, {0, 1.}, z}});

redeData = DimensionReduce[eData, Method ->  "PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"];
redData = DimensionReduce[data, Method ->  "PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"];
ListPlot[{redData, redeData}]
```

Gives the result as

[image: ReduceDimense for original data & EvenData]

Regardless undetected data is only a small part of the file.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what is that you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

*(Extended comment.)*

It appears that `DimensionReduce` on the event data `eData` is going to use a feature extractor that puts `eData` in an 8-dimensional space, and then the reduction is done over that 8-dimensional representation.

[image]

Compare with the same results for `data`. It appears that `data` is not changed before the reduction.

[image]